# Strange replication between volumes

Tags: filesystems, replication

In one PC i found strange issue: there are two folders C:\folder1\ and D:\folder2 on it, when i create file in one of them (either), the same file instantly appears in another folder. What can cause this replication? The system is Windows Server 2003 SP2. Both C and D drives are shared.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what caused the issue. It was reparse point, which I delete with `fsutil reparsepoint delete c:\folder1` command